# Return PDF generated with FPDF in Flask on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf, flask, fpdf

I am trying to create a flask app which convert uploaded image to pdf file.
I can generate a PDF with an image using the code below. How can I return the generated PDF from a Flask hosted on google app engine?

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF()
img = input('enter file name')
g = img + '.jpg'
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image(g, 50, 50)
pdf.output(img + '.pdf', 'F')
```

below is code which upload and store image in blobstore

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, Response, url_for
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.api import images
from fpdf import FPDF
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


class Image(ndb.Model):
    blob = ndb.BlobProperty()
    mimetype = ndb.StringProperty()
    alt = ndb.StringProperty()
    caption = ndb.TextProperty()


@app.route('/')
def render_form():
    return render_template('/form.html')


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def handle_upload():
    image = Image(
        alt=request.form.get('alt'),
        caption=request.form.get('caption')
    )
    uploaded_file = request.files.get('file')
    image.mimetype = uploaded_file.mimetype
    image_data = uploaded_file.stream.read()
    image.blob = images.resize(image_data, 256, 256)
    image.put()
    return redirect(url_for('serve_image', id=image.key.urlsafe()))



@app.route('/img/<id>')
def serve_image(id):
    image_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=id)
    image = image_key.get()
    return Response(image.blob, mimetype=image.mimetype)
```

so how will i convert uploaded image file(stored in blobstore) to pdf

actually google app engine dont allow to upload image in temp folder ,we have to upload it in blobstore first ,thats why I am asking how will i convert image (stored in blobstore)to pdf .please help me